# gdb debugging pointer to a structure unreadable value

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, watch

I have an issue with my pointer to a structure variable. I just started using GDB to debug the issue. The application stops when it hits on the line of code below due to Segmentation fault. ptr_var is a pointer to a structure

```
ptr_var->page = 0;
```

I understand that it sets the value "0" to a member "page" of my structure pointer which is no longer in memory. I need to know exactly when did the variable ptr_var is lost from memory. However, I cound't execute command

```
awatch *ptr
```

or

```
rwatch *ptr
```

GDB says "Expression cannot be implemented with read/access watchpoint."

I was only able to execute the watch command and it just stops on the same line of code above

```
watch *ptr_var


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Watchpoint 2: *ptr_var
Old value = {
...
}
New value = <unreadable>
func1 (ptr_var=0x0) at sample.c:1829
1829                ptr_var->page = 0;

    ptr_var->page = 0;
```

What is the best or proper way to debug the variable ptr_var? So that I can catch the instruction when ptr_var lost its memory. My backtrace in GDB contains a lot of library calls.

I'm a newbie to GDB and an average C programmer. Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*UPDATE:
I just discovered in GDB that ptr_var is overwritten with a NULL address. The old address is still in memory and I can still print the values of the struct members using the old address

Comment: If you want to monitor when `ptr_var` changes then you should do `watch ptr_var` (ie, without the `*` ).

Comment: It will still stop on the same line of code: ptr_var->page = 0;
I coudn't tell on what instruction did the variable ptr_var lost its memory

Comment: Oh, just noticed it's not stopping because of the watch but because of the SEGV. It means you probably have never set `ptr_var` correctly at all before that point.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. Indeed, you are correct that GDB breaks because of the segmentation fault and not because of the watch command. Is there a possible way that I can execute a command on GDB to break when ptr_var lost its memory?

Comment: The point is that it doesn't look like it "lost its memory". It looks like it was never set at all. If it is set anywhere then the watch would have picked it up. If you don't believe that then try a different approach - find where you think that var is set in the code. Put a breakpoint at that line(s) of code and I think you will find it never hits any of those breakpoints.

Comment: I understand that the watch command only breaks when the variable being watched is written. However, I have not written into the variable or the members of the struct, but I am just passing the value of a struct member to a function and after it returns to the main function, ptr_var became NULL

Comment: That's the point. If you have not written to the variable then it is not intialised. Someone needs to set that variable to point to valid memory. Who is responsible for doing that? Your debugging is showing that no one has set that variable to a valid value and that it is `0` when `func` is called. If you want more specifics then show your full code in context. No one can tell you what's wrong without the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93024/discussion-between-marss-and-kaylum).